# Importing Bootstrap CDN-mediated styles into the Sub-theme's Style.css

Tags: theming

I've opened a fresh Bootstrap sub-theme. This sub-theme is empty of any styles. What is the right way to import the CDN-mediated style sheets into the (now-empty) Style.css of the sub-theme?

It's a long story why I don't want to use the Bootstrap CDN in that particular case but I really just want everything to be local.

How could I import the basic Bootstrap Stylesheets into my Sub-theme's Style.css file and finally use everything local?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Bootstrap Library](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_library) module to do that. quoting from the project page:

> This module is fully compatible with the Bootstrap Theme. If you wish,
>   use it as an alterative to the CDN loading.

Comment: Isn't there a manual way? Just in case?

Comment: there is take a look at your subtheme.info file and instruction in this page [this page](https://www.drupal.org/node/1978010). but I think using the library is more flexible

Comment: After enabling, should I now open a directory at sites/all/libraries by the name "Bootstrap" (all lowercase I guess) and extract a clean Bootstrap-install from http://getbootstrap.com ? That's all?

Comment: Yes, that's all.

Comment: In getbootstrap.com here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download there are 3 download options: Bootstrap, source code, and SASS. I guess "Bootstrap" which is compiled is what I need but I may be wrong: Could you please update your answer with these details and say what is most fitted and how to set the folders inside the newly-created "bootstrap" library folder? Thank you,

Comment: Can you please detail on this in the answer?

Comment: @benos, my answer is answering your question. how to setup the libraries is not the scope for the question.  The answer is clearly directed you to the right direction. you even accepted the answer then unaccepted it!

Comment: I know what I did but when I came to did that I've seen various versions of Bootstrap and I think that an answer that totally answers the question and doesn't let you gamble on what version is the right one - should mention it in the first place. To save time for anyone who will come across it and deliver the most precise direction.